# Why does my addEventListener not work sometimes, but work other times?

Tags: javascript, button, addeventlistener

My `addEventListener` works most of the time and does nothing at other times. For example, I made a button with `createElement` and then used `appendChild`, and added some attributes to it, one of which is `onclick`. It should add an event listener for space, and then do stuff, but it does not.

I even added an `alert` so that when I clicked it would do both, and it alerted me, but still no luck.

I copied and pasted it into the dev console and it worked fine, but never seems to work when I put it in a button. Thanks! Also, sorry if I need to add anything else, I am kind of new here. Again, Thank you!

```js
const fly = document.createElement("button")
parentElement.appendChild(fly)
fly.innerText = "Enable Flying (Spacebar)"
setAttribute("onclick", "addEventListener('keypress', function(e){if(e.key == ' '){player.yvel = -5}})}")
```

It did nothing, and didn't even throw any errors. I tried again in console, worked fine.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It's almost always wrong to add an event listener inside another event listener. Every time you click on `fly` it will add another `keypress` listener to the window.

Comment: Don't use `setAttribute` to add event listeners. Use `fly.addEventListener("click", ...)`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Issues like this are normally caused because you've not put your JS code in DOMContentLoaded handler, or have included it too early in the page. This is causing a race condition between the DOM loading and the JS being executed on elements which don't yet exist.